# Incrementing padding in SASS

Tags: sass

I would like to have children elements to have padding incremented by 10px.

I've tried the following:

```
$lpad: 10px;
$i: 1;

@for $i through 20 {
    .myEm:nth-child($i) {
        padding-left: $lpad * $i;            
    }
    $i: $i + 1;
}
```

Looks right but doesn't seem to work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a loop. Even if it were, this isn't how CSS works.

You can do something like this if your elements are nested:

```
.el { 
  padding-left: 10px;
  > .el {
    padding-left: 20px;
  }
}
```

If your elements are siblings:

```
@for $i from 1 through 20 {
  .simLvl:nth-child(#{$i}) {
    margin-left: $lpad * $i;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is somewhat what I was going when my CSS compiles, but because I can not tell how many children I will have in the final code this must be done programmatically utilizing SASS.

Comment: Thanks! That looks great. I must be still missing something. Here's my JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5v9pn8cx/

Comment: @santa Yes, you're still using your original code trying to increment `$i` inside of the loop, and your syntax is all wonky.

Comment: Are you talking about OP or JSfiddle? I removes increment in the fiddle...

Comment: @santa You updated it and had two other issues: 1) you were using `nth-child` on a child of `simLvl` that only has a single instance per `.simLvl`. 2) inline elements don't have margins.

Comment: @santa I've updated my answer to use the same class as your code in JSFiddle and applied `margin-left` instead of `padding-left` to match.